# Calling extjs function from my gsp

Tags: extjs

I am trying to call a extjs function from my gsp
basically the function is in deleteFiling.js which I am referencing at the gsp header

```
<g:javascript src="deleteConfirm.js"></g:javascript>
```

and deleteConfirm.js:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL = appContextRoot
+ '/js/extjs/resources/images/default/s.gif';
var theme = appContextRoot
+ "/js/extjs/resources/css/xtheme-gray.css";
Ext.util.CSS.swapStyleSheet("theme", theme)

Ext.QuickTips.init();
Ext.form.Field.prototype.msgTarget = 'side';

function confirmFiling(){
    Ext.MessageBox.show({
        title:'Commit Confirmation',
        msg: 'You are about to <strong>Delete</strong> the entire <strong>Filing</strong>. This \n action cannot be reversed. \n\nAre you sure you want to Proceed',
        buttons: Ext.MessageBox.YESNO,
        fn: processDelete,
        icon: Ext.MessageBox.QUESTION
    });
}})
```

and I am calling the confirmFiling function like this:

```
<g:link action="deleteFiling" id="${filingInstance.id}" onclick="confirmFiling()"> <img src="${resource(dir:'images',file:'trash.gif')}" title="Delete" />
```

I keep getting function is undefined.
I know I could do this without extjs, but my question is how can I call extjs function from a html or gsp file.

Thanks

Comment: was the answer below helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Your code defines confirmFiling function as a local property of an anonymous function that you pass into Ext.onReady.

However your onclick event is trying to call a confirmFiling function that it expects to find in the global scope (same as the window scope).

If this is the entirety of your code and you will write no more functions, modules or other components using Ext than you can just create a global varaible and set it equal to the confirmFiling function like this:

```
myGlobalVar = function confirmFiling(){...}
```

Then myGlobalVar is reachable from your onclick event handler. Notice there is no `var` declaration for a global variable. If you put `var` in front of it then it becomes a local.

The other (better) approach is to define a namespace and create your function within that namespace. Here is an example: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext-method-ns 
By the way I assume you are using ExtJS 3x.
 Once you define your function within your namespace then you call it through your namespace in the event handler.